# Adding Map Info Windows Value From JSON by Clicking on Table Rows

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Can you please take a look at this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/J2B3K/9/) and let me know how I can add Map Info window for each marker on click on Markers OR related row in the table which contain the Title value from the json file?
Here is the json data sample:

```
var data = {"markers":[
    { "latitude":11.606503, "longitude":122.712637, "title":"Copenhagen" },
    { "latitude":11.585988, "longitude":122.757084, "title":"Barcelona"}

]};
```

I need to use the titles in the info windows.

Update I tried to add these snippest to the code

```
bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, data.description);
function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, strDescription) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(strDescription);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
```

but still not working

Comment: can you add the JS code here and/or in jsfiddle that shows where you create the `infowindow`?

Comment: Hi Duncan , here is the sample with added code http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/p67ZL/1/

Answer (score 0):

You want to use data.markers[p].title not data.description

http://jsfiddle.net/p67ZL/2/

```
    for (p = 0; p < data.markers.length; p++) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.markers[p].latitude, data.markers[p].longitude),
            map: map,
            draggable: true,
            title: "marker " + p,
            id: p
        });

        $('#myTable tbody:eq(1)').append('<tr class=' + marker.id + '><td>' + data.markers[p].title + '</td><td>' + data.markers[p].latitude + '</td><td>' + data.markers[p].longitude + '</td></tr>');

        bindMarker(marker);
        bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, data.markers[p].title);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you a lot geocodezip. just one thing left, can you please let me know how to do this also on the rows on the table? for example if someone clicks on "Barcelona" it The info windows for associated markers pops up? there is one mino issue with your code also, as soon as user drag the markers the Name in the row changes to "marker0,... ". Once again thanks